# How to reuse Calculated Field

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a Calculated Field 1 that I renamed to MagicPiField.

I have Calculated Field 2 in which I want to use the values of MagicPiField (instead of copying the formula of MagicPiField)

But when I try to reference MagicPiField, I get NAME ERROR

How can I reuse the values of a caculated field in the same pivot table ?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample sheet where you are trying this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't pivot within a pivot table. (Calculate a column from a calculated column of the same pivot table).

You can work around this by:

- Building an expression that includes the first calculation in the second calculated column's formula.

OR:

- Create a second table taking the data from the first pivot table.

---

**For your example:**

An expression for the second Calculated field could be like the following:

> `=(Count+3.14)*2`

---

**Note:**

The Calculated fields has to be a function of the input data for the pivot table.

Comment: How to build such expression in your first suggested option  ?